# How to remove oracle database express edition

Tags: oracle, uninstallation, oracle-xe, oracle18c

[image]

***please help anyone what am i missing to remove from my system.***

Comment: I have solved the problem.after deleting the program data the service is not yet removed. So to remove the service fire up an administrator cmd and run `sc stop OracleServiceXE` and `sc delete OracleServiceXE`. that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. There's no *Uninstaller* for 11gXE so you'll have to do it manually. According to Documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW135):

- go to Windows **Control Panel**
- run "Add or Remove Programs" or "Programs and Features" (depending on your Windows version)
- select "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition"
- click "Change/Remove" or "Uninstall" (again, depending on Windows version)

That would be all.

Comment: I have Uninstalled from control panel. I deleted the program data manually before Uninstalling it from control panel

Comment: I want to know where does the installation store its data. all of them .I will delete them or revert changes if any. m loosing hope and starting to fear that i will soon need a refresh or reinstallation of windows

Comment: You have some questions, and I don't have those answers, sorry. Perhaps it would be OK if you removed it from Control Panel instead of manually deleting files. Check Windows Registry and delete entries related to XE; maybe it'll help. Don't forget to save registry backup, just in case!

Answer (score 3):

I was using the uninstall functionality from the "Programs and Features" but got the same error. I was planning to reinstall it. After manually deleted the 18c related records from the regedit:

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE

and running the following commands from the command line

- sc delete OracleOraDB18Home1MTSRecoveryService
- sc delete OracleOraDB18Home1TNSListener
- sc delete OracleJobSchedulerXE
- sc delete OracleRemExecServiceV2
- sc delete OracleServiceXE
- sc delete OracleVssWriterXE
- sc delete OracleXEMTSRecoveryService

OracleRemExecServiceV2 (got
error but still okay)
The installer was working correctly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Their uninstaller is broken. After removing from programs and features.. it still leaves the services running. So you have to manually remove them.. before trying a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Done manually deleted oracle services and program files but the Oracle installer still detected oracle 18c installed in the system.
In the end  found out that, the installer is checking  the registry below

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{C220B7FD-3095-47FC-A0C0-AE49DE6E320A}]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\DF7B022C5903CF740A0CEA94EDE623A0\InstallProperties]
```

Before deleting the registry from above, search and remove all the registry keys which having  `C220B7FD`  and  `DF7B022`.

No problem reinstall 18c after cleaning up the registry.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** *Follow this only if you are having too much trouble reinstalling oracle_xe and want to install fresh, since it deletes almost all of the data.*

First, Stop the Current Running Services:

> *Open an elevated prompt*

- `sc stop OracleServiceXE`
- same for other services( *LISTENER, JOB_SCHEDULER* etc.)
- Run Uninstaller from **Control-Panel** -> **Add or Remove Programs**.
- Or do it from terminal by running `msiexec /x {C220B7FD-3095-47FC-A0C0-AE49DE6E320A}`

Second, See if there are any remaining services related to oracle, if these exist:

> Remove them all by running following commands:

- `sc delete OracleServiceXE`
- `sc delete OracleOraDB21Home1TNSListener`
- `sc delete OracleOraDB21Home1MTSRecoveryService`
- `sc delete OracleJobSchedulerXE`

Third, Remove your install directories and environment variables:

- `DEFAULT_INSTALLDIR = C:\app\[USERNAME]\product\21.0.0\`
- Save `<INSTALL_DIR>\oradata\XE`, If you dont want your local database files to be deleted.

Fourth, type **regedit.msc** in **RUN_BOX -> 'WIN + R'**

Delete the keys at following locations:

- Delete keys with prefix `Ora, Oracle, Orcl, or EnumOra` at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.
- Delete the `ORACLE` key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`
- Delete oracle related keys at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software`
- Delete `Oracle group key` at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`
- Expand all the subkeys under ODBC and remove any **Oracle-related ODBC driver** keys at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC` except for `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle key`.
- Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`, delete keys that begin with `Oracle` or `OraWeb`
- Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ Eventlog\Application`, delete all keys that begin with `Oracle`.
- These guides are from : [Removing_Oracle_Database_Software](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14316/deinstall.htm#CIHIHDAD)

Finally, remove local oracle groups if needed:

- Run -> `net localgroup` in `cmd`.
- You will see the list of groups information on your device.
- Remove all oracle related groups by:
- Running -> `net localgroup <group_name> /delete`
- Group name mostly have prefix `ORA_`.

This is my first time posting, because I had alot of issues during reinstallation of oracle_xe, and I am not that good with databases.

- `Do suggest some fixes, if some of the details are not correct`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what helped me:
The reason is simple, the uninstaller only does half a job.

If you run the services.msc utility (Windows +R, type services.msc), scroll down to the Oracle named services and you will see a few that are still there. You need to get rid of those as follows:

start

Search for cmd

Right-click, run as adminsitrator

When it runs:

sc delete service_name

For each and every OracleXE service you see.

Then try the installer again.

Source: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4209872/cannot-reinstall-xe-18c-after-doing-an-uninstall